# Barcode for identification of separator pages

Tags: qr-code, barcode

I want to use a barcode as a way to identify a separator page in a stack of scanned documents.

I want to figure out the best type of barcode to use for that.

Here is the current situation:  The user scans in a stack of paper (1-10 pages) that represent one document.

It would be much faster for them to scan in a bigger stack of paper.

To accommodate this I am going to create a page with a special pattern on it and write a C# program that will look for that pattern and create separate documents based on those pages separating the documents.

I am writing my own program because I will be looking for barcodes on the actual documents as well so I need custom code.

My question is:

Which barcode technology will be the best for the separator page?

My gut tells me to use QR Code; but I would like hear what others have to say.

Comment: Are faxed documents a consideration?  Faxing tends to blur and distort images more than regular photocopy/scanner machines.

Comment: Also, what are your payload requirements for the barcode?  What do you actually want to encode?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your scanning code can rely on your barcode being relatively level with the page and the amount of data that you want to scan is less than 50 or so characters, you don't need to go 2D with your symbology. I would recommend Code 128.

If you aren't relying on a library, it is much easier write the code to spot and decode a raster with a predefined pattern of 1's and 0's. Using QR code or any other 2D symbology (Datamatrix or PDF417) should only be considered necessary if you need a high volume of characters as the decoding of a 2D symbol is much more complex.

This assumes that you also have control over the symbology that will be used within the documents and they follow the same constraints.